# C# compare datagridview cells to int number

Tags: c#, winforms

when I have a datagridview and I need to compare a cell with a number and then color the cell accordingly

```
 private void DGV2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            
           
            if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) > 96.69)
            {
                DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                
            }
             if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) > 94)
            {
                DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) < 94)
            {
                DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
}
```

it's not showing me correctly

Comment: well it will never be LightGreen, you need an else

Comment: Why are you using the `ColumnIndex` of the cell? Surely it's the `Value` of the cell you should be using?

Comment: Also, don't use the same complex expression multiple times. Get the value you need once and assign it to a variable, then you that variable multiple times. You're getting the same cell 6 times and the `Style` and `ColumnIndex` of that cell 3 times each. That's madness. Get the cell once, then get the `ColumnIndex` (or `Value`) and `Style` once each.

Comment: Also, why are you using the same cell every time in that code? The whole point of events with names that begin with "Cell" is that they are raised for each cell as needed and the specific cell the event is being raised for can be accessed via the `e` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
        if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) > 96.69)
        {
            DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            
        } else if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) > 94)
        {
            DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].ColumnIndex) < 94)
        {
            DGV2.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }
```

Comment: You should probably read [jmcilhinney's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831208/c-sharp-compare-datagridview-cells-to-int-number#comment132063860_74831208) -- The comparison, `> 96.69`, also may suggest that the Cell's ValueType could be `double` (or may convert to `double`), so `Convert.ToInt32()` would throw

Answer (score 0):

I already found a way to do it, thank you very much for the answers, they helped me, I typed double and had the wrong input format (shame on me) thank you very much, I am showing how I solved it, in case it could help someone.

```
 private void DGV3_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = DGV3.Rows[11];
        label3.Text = (selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        label3.Text = label3.Text.Replace("%", "");
        double someDouble = 96.69;
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(someDouble);
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(label3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int vstup = Convert.ToInt32(d);

        if (vstup > y)
        {
            DGV3.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

        }
         if (vstup >= 94)
        {
            DGV3.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        }
        if (vstup < 94)
        {
            DGV3.Rows[11].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }
```